# Temporarily monitor CloudFormation stack events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to write a command line tool that, among other things, monitors CloudFormation stack events for a particular stack and pretty-prints them to the console.

The out-of-the box solution is to repeatedly poll `describe-stack-events`. This is not ideal — you get the latest 200 events every time, and you're limited by the polling rate.

CloudFormation can also log events to an SNS topic. However, as far as I know, SNS is designed to send events to long-lasting destinations like lambdas and email addresses; it's not made for a script to temporarily listen to a topic.

I don't know much about AWS's various event and queueing services. I'm looking for a solution that is:

- Cheap/easy.
- Low-latency. (I'd like to see events in real time as a deployment is happening.)
- Amenable to short-term subscriptions from a Node app or somesuch on my local machine.

I do not need:

- Any sort of storage or view into past events.
- Very high reliability. (This is a convenience tool for devs.)

Suggestions?

Comment: Would slack be an option? I know a way to do this quick, easy, and cheap through slack in real time.

Comment: That's a good idea, and I might implement that as well. But for this particular use case, I'm looking for something that can run locally, e.g. in a terminal.

Comment: You could make a lambda that pushes new updates to a sqs queue and have your cli poll the queue. This way you would not have to deal with a flood of events each time.  Not sure if there is an easy way without polling. You potentially could open a http endpoint that could receive the sns message, but that would not be easy.